# Postgres error: column does not exist when using json field

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-11

Postgres version 11.10

Here is my postgres schema which uses a jsonb field

```
create table data(
    key       char(32), --md5 
    time      int  NOT NULL,
    output    jsonb NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (key,time)
)
```

Here are two queries that works just fine

```
select distinct on(key) key   from data ORDER BY  key,time DESC
select distinct on(key) key,output   from data ORDER BY  key,time DESC
```

the problem is this query

```
select distinct on(key) key,output-->details   from data ORDER BY  key,time DESC
```

I keep getting the error

> column "key" does not exist

Any idea why?

Comment: You might be interested in [this](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don't_Do_This#Don.27t_use_char.28n.29)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, thanks for the tip, i'll use text from now on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`--` starts a comment that lasts until the end of the line (see the syntax highlighting in your question). So the query effectively is

```
select distinct on(key) key,output
```

Since that has no `FROM` clause, the column reference `key` causes an error.

You probably are looking for the `->>` operator:

```
select distinct on(key)
       key,
       output ->> 'details'
from data
ORDER BY  key,time DESC;
```

Comment: brilliant. thank you, that solved the problem